# random values from db in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, random

How can I retrive random random ItemIDs from the list of existing ItemIDs in ItemID column intge db, given below is the sqlcommand I've used.

```
(SqlCommand RetrieveComm =new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM item_k WHERE ItemID='" +intGetRequest+ "'", searchCon))
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified which RDBMS you are using.

If you are using SQL Server, this will return N random rows:

```sql
SELECT TOP N    
    SomeColumn 
FROM     
    SomeTable
ORDER BY     
    CHECKSUM(NEWID())
```

Comment: I didnt get your code! I need to get the itemIDs as well as other values.

Comment: So SELECT TOP N * FROM item_k ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID()), no?!

Answer (score 2):

Is the `itemID` column in the database, a contiguous list of numbers ?

If so, you can just do...

```
Random r = new Random();
int x = r.Next(1, MAX_ID_FROM_DB);
```